# nexus maven domain suffix incorrect

Tags: maven, nexus

**Architecture:**

Company nexus is setup on box1:8081 

Hudson is setup on box1:8090

Both above systems have proxies and succesfully can access the public internet (confirmed via Nexus's ability to browse remote, and Hudson being able to build a maven project as expected, populating a fresh .m2/repository that hudson is using)

However - When i edit the settings.xml to use the nexus mirror (as per multiple instructions on line ie: [here](http://www.andrejkoelewijn.com/wp/2010/03/09/getting-started-with-nexus-maven-repository-manager/)), rename my repository to repository_old (so i can track the new dependencies being acquired if there are issues) and then run a simple maven target like clean or install, i get an odd situation.

The command terminal will output

```
Downloading: http://box1:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.1/maven-dependency-plugin-2.1.pom
4 KB   
[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected <!DOCTYPE but is f91612c35130352fb87d878ad11e365864726080 for http://box1:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.1/maven-dependency-plugin-2.1.pom
4 KB
[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected <!DOCTYPE but is 45ab043cf424aacf8b314b01bdae110516db8d1f for http://box1:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.1/maven-dependency-plugin-2.1.pom
Downloaded: http://box1:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.1/maven-dependency-plugin-2.1.pom (4 KB at 1.0 KB/sec)
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.1 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
Downloading: http://box1:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.1/maven-dependency-plugin-2.1.jar
4 KB   
[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected <!DOCTYPE but is ac40ff8e0340bd60e08433c1440a699049d77126 for http://box1:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.1/maven-dependency-plugin-2.1.jar
4 KB   
[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected <!DOCTYPE but is 11b860e6a486fb2e5c1ffcc56d9240139dcfb2f0 for http://box1:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.1/maven-dependency-plugin-2.1.jar
Downloaded: http://box1:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.1/maven-dependency-plugin-2.1.jar (4 KB at 13.3 KB/sec)
```

And, in this example - the url

```
http://box1:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.1/maven-dependency-plugin-2.1.pom
```

Is accurate, and resolvable from my local workstation, AND the box1 environment.

However.  When i dig into the new repository folder (and subfolders) for org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.1/ 
and open up the maven-dependency-plugin-2.1.pom I see a network error of

```
The page http://www.box1.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.1/maven-dependency-plugin-2.1.pom Cannot be found
```

**Note the following issues:**

www prefix

.com suffix

no nexus port

Any idea what is mis-configured?  It feels like the nexus server is attempting to massage the incoming request URL and assuming (wrongly) domain suffix and port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After discussing with some fellow devop type friends around town, I was able to solve this by adding the fully qualified domain name in my maven settings.xml

I edited it to be

```
<mirror>
   <id>nexus</id>
   <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
   <url>http://box1.companyName.corp:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
</mirror>
```

intead of

```
<mirror>
   <id>nexus</id>
   <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
   <url>http://box1:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
 </mirror>
```

And my issue was resolved.